# How do I prevent my long press function to be fired after the first run?

Tags: javascript, long-press

I'm trying to build an interface where, after a long press of one `<li>`, the pressed element gets toggled `class="active"` and the `<ul>` attribute `data-edit` becomes true.

The `data-edit="true"` is needed so that the other `li` elements won't need to be long pressed anymore in order to be toggled.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="container" data-edit="false">
    <li class="item" tabindex="0"></li>
    <li class="item" tabindex="0"></li>
    <li class="item" tabindex="0"></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the JS:

```
function longPress() {
  const lists = document.querySelectorAll("[data-edit=false]");
  const delay = 800;

  lists.forEach((list) => {
    const listItems = list.querySelectorAll("li");

    listItems.forEach((listItem) => {
      listItem.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        clearTimeout(pressTimer);
      });

      listItem.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
        pressTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          listItem.classList.toggle("active");
          list.setAttribute("data-edit", "true");
        }, delay);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The problem is that once I long press on one `<li>`, the `<ul>` parent remains stored in the `list` variable and so, long pressing on the other `<li>` elements, results on their classes getting toggled to active as well.

How can I update the iterated `list` variable so that the function doesn't go through after the first long press?

Comment: so remove the events?

Comment: @epascarello Yes that'll do it but I really cannot figure out how to do so. Inside of the `"mousedown"` function I am setting the attributes of the targeted list to `"data-edit="true"` so shouldn't the `list` variable be undefined? And therefore stop the other `listItems` from getting passed onto the function?

Comment: Once you select an item it does not change what you selected when you alter it.

Comment: So when you want to remove the mousedown and up is it only for that UI or is it all ULs?

Comment: Oh I see! 

Basically the main objective of this whole function is to get the `<ul>` into some sort of a "edit mode" once one of the `<li>` is long pressed. 

After the first long press event the user should be able to `classList.toggle.("active")` all of the `<li>` elements, one by one, just by clicking on them.